# After setting tree node height, treeview scroll incorrectly

Tags: c#, winforms

```
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dictionary<int, TreeNode> map = new Dictionary<int, TreeNode>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            TreeNode node = new TreeNode(i.ToString());
            if (i % 10 == 0)
                _tree.Nodes.Add(node);
            map.Add(i, node);
            if (i % 10 != 0)
            {
                map[Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(i / 10.0)) * 10].Nodes.Add(node);
                node.SetNodeHeight(2);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static class TreeViewExtendMethod
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct TVITEMEX
    {
        public Mask mask;
        public IntPtr item;
        public uint state;
        public uint stateMask;
        public IntPtr pszText;
        public int cchTextMax;
        public int iImage;
        public int iSelectedImage;
        public int iChildren;
        public IntPtr lParam;
        public int iIntegral;

        // ... plus some windows 6+ crap
    }

    [Flags]
    enum Mask : uint
    {
        Text = 1,
        Image = 2,
        Param = 4,
        State = 8,
        Handle = 16,
        SelectedImage = 32,
        Children = 64,
        Integral = 128,
    }
    public static int GetNodeHeight(this TreeNode tn)
    {
        TVITEMEX tvix = new TVITEMEX();
        tvix.mask = Mask.Handle | Mask.Integral;
        tvix.item = tn.Handle;
        tvix.iIntegral = 0;
        IntPtr hParam=Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(tvix));
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(tvix, hParam, false);
        win32.SendMessage(tn.TreeView.Handle, win32.TVM_GETITEM, IntPtr.Zero, hParam);
        return tvix.iIntegral;
    }

    public static void SetNodeHeight(this TreeNode tn, int height)
    {
        TVITEMEX tvix = new TVITEMEX();
        tvix.mask = Mask.Handle | Mask.Integral;
        tvix.item = tn.Handle;
        tvix.iIntegral = height;
        IntPtr hParam=Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(tvix));
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(tvix, hParam, false);
        win32.SendMessage(tn.TreeView.Handle, win32.TVM_SETITEM, IntPtr.Zero, hParam);
    }
}
```

The above is the sample code, after using the PINV to change the node height manually, when click in the bottom of the scroll bar, the treeview will scroll which should not scroll at all as it just a click.

At first, I think it may be caused by scroll bar, it doesn't work as expected after I set the scroll Msg para (8) to end scroll. At last, while catching the scroll msg (0x115), exits the WndProc, and then it works. I have no idea what is going on as I can't find any msg can cancel scroll except setting the wParam to 8 which is certainly not work.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find a solution, though not elegant, but it should works.
Here is the solution,

```
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x115)
        {
            if (((int)m.WParam & 5) == (5) ||
                ((int)m.WParam & 4) == (4)
                )
            {
                int para = (int)m.WParam;
                int temp = (para - (para % 2 == 0 ? 4 : 5)) >> 16;

                // store the current position, if the position doesn't change, no need to handle
                if (temp == pos)
                    return;
                else
                    pos = temp;
            }
            if (((int)m.WParam & 8) == 8)
                return;

            //Debug.WriteLine(m.WParam);
            //if (DisableScroll)
            //    return;
            //    //m.WParam = (IntPtr)8;
            //SCROLLINFO si = new SCROLLINFO();
            //si.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(si);
            //si.fMask = (int)(ScrollInfoMask.SIF_POS | ScrollInfoMask.SIF_PAGE | ScrollInfoMask.SIF_RANGE | ScrollInfoMask.SIF_TRACKPOS);
            //GetScrollInfo(this.Handle, 1, ref si);
            ////Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Max pos:{0}, Min pos: {1}", si.nMin, si.nMax));
            //Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("wParam:{0} hParam:{1}", m.WParam, m.LParam));
            //Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("It page size: {0}, position: {1}, range: {2}, track pos: {3}", si.nPage, si.nPos, si.nPage, si.nTrackPos));
            //if (si.nPage + Math.Max(si.nPos, si.nTrackPos) >= si.nMax)
            //{
            //    return;
            //}
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```